# Submenu for a listview of Navigation drawer by using Master detail Page

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, navigation-drawer, submenu

I want to implement sub-items in a list view which is in the Navigation drawer(Master detail page).
I implemented the code, but it's not working.
Please check the below Github link for my code.

https://github.com/priyam1996/NavigationSubMenuProject

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

            HotelsGroupViewModel viewModel = new HotelsGroupViewModel();
            HotelsList.ItemsSource = viewModel.Items;

            this.IsPresented = false;
            Detail = new NavigationPage(new Dashboard());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<StackLayout x:Name="hotelStack" Padding="1,0,1,0" >
            <ListView
                x:Name="HotelsList"
                BackgroundColor="White"
                IsGroupingEnabled="True"
                IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
                IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadHotelsCommand}"
                >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  VerticalOptions="Center">
                                    <Label
                                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                                        FontAttributes="Bold"
                                        FontSize="Medium"
                                        Text="{Binding .RoomName}"
                                        TextColor="Black"
                                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />                                  
                            </StackLayout>                                   
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                           <Grid >
                               <Label
                                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                                            FontSize="Small"
                                            Text="{Binding Name}"
                                            TextColor="Gray"
                                            VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                                <Image x:Name="ImgA" Source="{Binding StateIcon}"  Margin="0,0,5,0" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                                <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference currentPage}, Path=BindingContext.RefreshItemsCommand}"  NumberOfTapsRequired="1" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Grid>                               
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
```

Click [here](https://github.com/ishrakland/ListViewWithSubListView)!
This works as well.

Comment: getting errors.

Invalid property path syntax. ListViewWithSubListView Hotels.xaml 28

No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimaryDark'.

Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog'.

Comment: Firstly, download repo from given link then restore packages and run project.

Comment: Did restore packages..Still getting the same errors.

Comment: this sample works fine at mine end . which version of visual studio and operating system you are using? Make sure packages are restored, without any network proxy may be your network have firewall proxies.

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2017 version and Widows OS. I restored the packages

Comment: I will suggest, Kindly update your visual studio for better development.

Comment: I created a new project and pasted all the code. It runs successfully.But List didn't binded to my navigation drawer listview.Please check my code of MainPage() custuctor.I modified some code to bind the list to list view.

Comment: post your code with description, accept answer if it useful for you otherwise not for community.

Comment: It's done..But I didn't use a list view for that. I used stack layout and i displayed the data in a static manner.
Thanks for Your help.